# Using SerialPort class to read response from connected device

Tags: c#, serial-port, com-port

I'm using C#'s `SerialPort` class to try and send a `AT` command to a device and get a response back. I've verified it works correctly in HyperTerminal, if I send a command of `AT` it responds back with `OK`. However, in my console app, if I send `AT`, it replies back with an echo `AT`. The code is below, any insight into what I'm doing wrong in my receiving code would be greatly appreciated:

```
ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ComPort_DataReceived);

public void Open()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            //close port if already open.
            if (ComPort.IsOpen)
            {
                ComPort.Close();
            }
            //setup port.
            ComPort.PortName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortName"].ToString();
            ComPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaudRate"]);
            ComPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            ComPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            ComPort.DataBits = 8;
            ComPort.DtrEnable = true;
            ComPort.RtsEnable = true;
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HWFlowControlEnabled"]))
            {
                ComPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
            }
            //open port.
            Console.WriteLine("Opening port " + ComPort.PortName + "...");
            ComPort.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Opened port " + ComPort.PortName);
        }

void ComPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string message = ComPort.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED: " + message);
            if (message.IndexOf("OK") > -1)
            {
                ReceivedOK = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the default is to echo your commands back to you, then the OK.  Send an ATE0 first to turn off echo:

http://tigger.cc.uic.edu/depts/accc/network/dialin/modem_codes.html

Comment: Thanks for the response but didn't work. It echoes back ATE0 and then sends AT in two lines ("A" then "T"). Does hyperterminal send this command behind the scenes? If not, then why do I need to send this command from my program but it works without this command in HT?

Comment: Got it working, I wasn't adding \n\r to the commands as I wrote them to the port.

Comment: Did the \n\r stop the echo without the ATE0?  I thought prog's like hypertermianal sent that on connecting to the port.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the device (a modem I guess) is configured to echo all communication back. There are AT commands to turn echo on and off. Also, several hardware signalling approaches exist to control the flow of data. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control) for a basic overview.

It's quite a while (> 10 years actually) since I was doing modem communications, so I'm sorry in case my answer isn't 100% precise.